# Firebase OTP Timeout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

What is the default timeout value of the OTP Code sent to the device(ie the expiration time of the OTP) in firebase Phone Authentication. If so, is there any way to change it.

Answer (score 3):

You pass the duration right into the call to `verifyPhoneNumber`. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone):

> ```
> PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
>         phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
>         60,                 // Timeout duration
>         TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
>         this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
>         mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
> ```

Comment: But that timeout value corresponds to the sms-auto-retreival and not the otp code expiration. It is not the otp code timeout value.

Comment: Hmm... in that case I don't think it is documented, or can be modified.